# My Talend Open Studio keeps on crashing after sometime

Tags: java, ubuntu, memory-management, etl, talend

I am using Talend open studio(TOS_BD-20211109_1610-V8.0.1) in Ubuntu(22.04.2 LTS). However, I am encountering a persistent issue where the application crashes automatically after some time. I have attempted to resolve the problem by modifying the .ini file configurations and upgrading my Java version from 11 to 17. Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I am still facing the same problem with Talend Open Studio crashing unexpectedly.

These are the configurations in my TOS_BD-linux-gtk-x86_64.ini file.

```
-vmargs
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
--add-opens
java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Also attaching a screen shot of the error which pops up after crash.
[image]